# Why can I modify a const __restrict pointer but not a typdef'd version?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, constants, restrict-qualifier

Note: I'm using the objective C compiler that ships with the latest version of Xcode.

Why is it that this is legal:

```
void verySpecial(const float* __restrict foo, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

        // ... do special things ...

        ++foo;  // <-- Should be illegal to modify const pointer?
    }
}
```

However, if I use a typedef, it does what I think it should do.

```
typedef float* __restrict RFloatPtr;

void verySpecial(const RFloatPtr foo, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {

        // ... do special things ...

        ++foo;  // <-- Now this is a compiler error.
    }
}
```

So, what is different in the typedef'd case, and what don't I understand?  Reading about __restrict makes my brain hurt, and I'm not even sure it matters here.

Comment: First Apple's does not have objective-c compiler it is either from gcc or llvm.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Huh, what?

Comment: Whatever.  It's the compiler that comes with XCode.  The most recent version of XCode in the app store.

Comment: what are you gaining from the __restrict keyword, I know what `restrict` is supposed to do, but it is only a hint.

Comment: What error do you get in case 2? Because I don't get one (Xcode 4.6.2). Is your question about `const` or `restrict`?

Comment: Ah, Martin, yes, I forgot a const in the second example.  Should make more sense now. The error is "Read-only variable is not assignable".  I edited the code to include the const.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: I can't give you a good explanation or reference, but `const RFloatPtr foo` is equivalent to `float * const foo` and means that `foo` itself cannot be modified. That is different from `const float * foo` which means that the data pointed to by `foo` cannot be modified.

Comment: @H2CO3: It seems that you were on the right track. Perhaps you want to undelete your answer? - (The problem seems to be unrelated to `restrict`).

Comment: @MartinR Very well. I undeleted it. Thanks for confirming me.

Answer (score 0):

```
++foo;  // <-- Should be illegal to modify const pointer?
```

Yap. Modifying a const pointer is illegal. However, modifying a non-`const` pointer to something which is `const` isn't. I think you're confusing

```
const float *foo
```

with

```
float *const foo
```

Also, of course you can't modify a `restrict` pointer, because it doesn't make sense. `restrict` tells the compiler that the pointer is guaranteed not to overlap with other pointers. This assumption may no longer be true if you decrement or increment the pointer.